# Drupal 7 db_insert array error

Tags: php, database, drupal-7

I am trying to insert data from an array into a table and I get this error:

"Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to InsertQuery::values() must be an array, boolean given"

```
$query = db_insert('print_aura_list_brands')
  ->fields(array(
    'brand_id',
    'brand_name',
  ));

foreach ($data as $record) {
  $query->values($record);
}
$query->execute();
```

[Here is an image of the database table structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmuOG.png)

[Here is an image of the array results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8hwH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example link you posted (drupal.org/node/310079) you can make the insert work with multiple values, if you make some changes.

In your case, if $data is your second screenshot ("image of the array results") you can not just iterate over $data because the first element in that object is a boolean (status -> TRUE).

You want to iterate over (array) $data->results, except each result is an object, not an array which it needs to be.

```
$query = db_insert('print_aura_list_brands')
  ->fields(array(
    'brand_id',
    'brand_name',
  ));

foreach ($data->results as $record) {
  $query->values((array) $record);
}
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Phil! This really helped. For anyone else that might see this post, I also implemented objToArray($data) function to change all objects to arrays. I learned that foreach() can only iterate over an array. If I'm stating this incorrectly please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You use the **db_insert** function incorrectly. Should be like this:

```
db_insert('example_tabel')
  ->fields(array(
    'field1' => 'value1',
    'field2' => 'value2',
    ...,
  ))
  ->execute();
```

fields array should be 'FIELDNAME' => 'VALUE', not just fields.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!
I was using an example from https://www.drupal.org/node/310079 and it seems I'm still a bit confused.  I'm trying to loop through the records of an array and input the results into a table. Perhaps my question really is - how do I reference the values so they show each individual record?